# Evaluate $\int_0^1 e^x \ln(x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm struggling to evaluate the definite integral of $\int_0^1e^x\ln(x)dx$. By integration by parts I get the antiderivative to be $e^x\ln(x)-\operatorname{Ei}(x)$. Im having trouble evaluating the limits of integration. At x=1 I get $-\operatorname{Ei}(1)$ but at x=0 I cannot get a value. Wolfram alpha says the two sided limit as x approaches 0 does not exist but says that the definite integral is $\gamma - \operatorname{Ei}(1)$ and I cannot figure out why. If the limit as x approaches zero does not exist, how can Wolfram get a value for it? It may be possible to transform the integral to have bounds of $0$ to $\infty$ and use a property of the Laplace Transform that says $\int_0^{\infty}fg=\int_0^{\infty}\mathcal{L}(f)\mathcal{L}^{-1}(g)$ but this seems pretty far fetched. Any ideas as to how WFA got it's result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you evaluate an improper integral where its bound is a singularity, you don't take the limit as $x$ approaches that bound on both sides, as you can see from the [definition of improper integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral). In our case, the integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}e^{x}\ln\left(x\right)dx$ is improperly integrable because $\displaystyle \lim_{a\to 0^+} \int_{a}^{1}e^{x}\ln\left(x\right)dx$ converges.

For this quick calculation, we will use the Puiseux Series of the [Exponential Integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html)

$$\operatorname{Ei}(x) = \gamma + \ln(x) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{nn!}.$$

Indeed,

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}e^{x}\ln\left(x\right)dx &= \lim_{a\to 0^+} \int_{a}^{1}e^{x}\ln\left(x\right)dx \\
&= \lim_{a\to 0^+}\Big[e^x \ln(x) - \operatorname{Ei}(x)\Big]_{a}^{1} \\
&= e^1 \ln(1) - \operatorname{Ei}(1) - \lim_{a\to 0^+} \left(e^a \ln(a) - \operatorname{Ei}(a)\right) \\
&= -\operatorname{Ei}(1) - \lim_{a\to 0^+}\left(e^a \ln(a) - \left(\gamma + \ln(a) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{nn!}\right)\right) \\
&= -\operatorname{Ei}(1) - \lim_{a\to 0^+} \left(e^a \ln(a) - \ln(a)\right) + \lim_{a\to 0^+} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{nn!} + \lim_{a\to 0^+}\gamma \\
&= -\operatorname{Ei}(1) - 0 + 0 + \gamma \\
&= \gamma - \operatorname{Ei}(1). \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Try to solve it without using Puiseux series.

Comment: Is there something wrong with using that series? @MathFail

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_a^1 e^x\, \log(x)\,dx=\text{Ei}(a)-\text{Ei}(1)-e^a \log (a)$$  Using Taylor series
$$\text{Ei}(a)=(\log (a)+\gamma )+a+\frac{a^2}{4}+O\left(a^3\right)$$
$$e^a \log (a)=\log (a)+a \log (a)+\frac{1}{2} a^2 \log (a)+O\left(a^3\right)$$ As a total
$$\int_a^1 e^x\, \log(x)\,dx=(\gamma -\text{Ei}(1))+a (1-\log (a))+O\left(a^2\right)$$ and then the result.

What is nice is that, if we look for $a$ such that
$$I(a)=k$$ we have the *estimates*
$$a \sim \frac{(\gamma -\text{Ei}(1))-k}{W_{(0,-1)}\left(\frac{(\gamma -\text{Ei}(1))-k}{e}\right)}$$ where $W(.)$ is one of the real branches of Lambert function.

For example, using $k=-1.234$ gives
$$a_1=0.016422 \qquad \text{and} \qquad a_2=2.63303$$ while the exact solutions are $a_1=0.016273$ and $a_2=1.80916$.